# Chaining Promises in Coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

Is there a way to chain `Promises` together in Coffeescript. For example, consider the following javascript code,

```
return $.getJSON('/api/post.json')
  .then(function(response) {
    // do something
  })
  .then(function(response) {
    // do something
  })
  .then(null, function(err) {
    // do something
  });
```

Each of the `then's` is optional, and the final `then` needs to be returned by the function.
Currently I am writing this in coffeescript as,

```
promise = $.getJSON('/api/post.json')
promise = promise.then (response) ->
  // do something

promise = promise.then (response) ->
  // do something

promise = promise.then null, (err) ->
  // do something

return promise
```

Is there a better way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: You could also take a look at IcedCoffeeScript. It works a little differently, but it works quite well.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Ezekiel shows the right way, but it doesn't need the parentheses around the functions. Just do:

```
$.getJSON '/api/post.json' # As of CoffeeScript 1.7, you don't need the parentheses here either.
.then (response) ->
  # do something
  response # if you would not return anything, promise would be fulfilled with undefined
.then (response) ->
  # do something
  undefined # necessary to prevent empty function body
.then null, (err) ->
  # handle error
```

I think it's surprisingly clean.
The one thing that's relatively messy is when you need to add onRejected and onFulfilled handlers at the same time.

Note: Last time I checked, this did not work in CoffeeScript Redux, but this was a few months ago.

Note 2: You need at least one line of actual code (i.e. not just a comment) in each function body for this to work. Typically, you will, so it's not a big issue.

Comment: Downvoted because this does not compile in CoffeeScript 1.4.0 or 1.6.3 (latest). The parentheses as shown in my answer are required.

Comment: @EzekielVictor: Thanks for being vigilant. I just looked into it, and problem seems to be that the second part of the chain lacked a function body. The indented comment was seemingly not enough. I added an explicit "undefined" at the end so it compiles. I've never run into this issue because I've never had non-empty function bodies in these places.

Comment: Ah, thank you for replying. I removed DV... And I learned something useful there. ;)

Comment: $.getJSON('/api/post.json'.then(function(response) {
    return response;
  }).then(function(response) {
    return void 0;
  }).then(null, function(err) {}));

Comment: Note 2 is important. Spent the last 20min trying to figure out what was wrong. Comments alone in promises will not work or compile successfully with coffeescript.

Answer (score 14):

This is my personal favorite way to write promises, with a little bit extra indentation

```
doSomething = () -> new RSVP.Promise (resolve, reject) ->
  if 1 is 1
    resolve 'Success'
  else
    reject 'Error'

doSomething()
.then (res) ->
      console.log 'Step 1 Success Handler'

    , (err) ->
      console.log 'Step 1 Error Handler'

.then (res) ->
      console.log 'Step 2 Success Handler'

.then (res) ->
      console.log 'Step 3 Success Handler'

    , (err) ->
      console.log 'Step 3 Error Handler'
```

Which compiles to:

```
var doSomething;

doSomething = function() {
  return new RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if (1 === 1) {
      return resolve('Success');
    } else {
      return reject('Error');
    }
  });
};

doSomething().then(function(res) {
  return console.log('Step 1 Success Handler');
}, function(err) {
  return console.log('Step 1 Error Handler');
}).then(function(res) {
  return console.log('Step 2 Success Handler');
}).then(function(res) {
  return console.log('Step 3 Success Handler');
}, function(err) {
  return console.log('Step 3 Error Handler');
});
```

There are some instances where this works really well too:

```
step1Success = (res) -> console.log 'Step 1 Success Handler'
step1Error   = (err) -> console.log 'Step 1 Error Handler'

step2Success = (res) -> console.log 'Step 2 Success Handler'

step3Success = (res) -> console.log 'Step 3 Success Handler'
step3Error   = (err) -> console.log 'Step 3 Error Handler'

doSomething()
  .then(step1Success, step1Error)
  .then(step2Success)
  .then(step3Success, step3Error)
```

Tested on coffee-script v1.6.3

Comment: This works nicely, and the only thing that hung me up for a bit is ensuring you don't have any spaces in the code. This is probably common for those new to coffeescript, but I couldn't get code like that above to compile until I realized I had a single space in the set of tabs.

Answer (score 4):

This is probably the best you'll do:

```
$.getJSON('/api/post.json')
    .then( (response) ->
      # do something
    ).then( (response) ->
      # do something
    ).then null, (err) ->
      # do something
```

Note the parentheses surrounding the `then()` arguments. Nothing earth shattering but hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Loosing the parenthesis, as @Meryn Stol suggests makes it a tad better.

Comment: Loosing the parentheses?  I presume you mean losing them.  The thought of loosing parentheses upon the world is frightening indeed.